# Can I use LINQ without Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, ado.net

I am working on an old application which uses a 3 thier approach, however the connection to the database is made via a connection string only and data is manipulated through sql stored procedure.

Is it possible to use LINQ without adding an ADO.NET entity model?

Comment: [Entity Framework 6](http://www.nuget.org/packages/entityframework) includes support for code first stored procedures. Linq To Sql also supports stored procedures.

Answer (score 8):

LINQ itself can be used without the database stuff. [LINQ to Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397919.aspx), for instance. But are you asking if you can use LINQ to operate on the database directly without setting up any type of entity model? No, not really. Maybe you're a candidate for Entity Framework Code First, but its a little hard to tell based on your description of your setup.

Answer (score 2):

Linq as in linq-to-sql/linq-to-ef, which means that the SQL will be generated based upon your expression? **No**.

Linq as in query over the data-in-memory that was loaded using your stored procedures (which means that your queries won't be translated to SQL)? **Yes**.

Comment: could you please provide an example for the second scenario?

Answer (score 1):

LINQ to SQL uses [Object Relational Mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) which is what Entity Framework is.  So while you may be able to "not use Entity Framework", you're always dealing with some type of ORM.. which is what I think you wanted to avoid.